# Converting time period in strings to equivalent numeric days

Tags: python, datetime, nlp, integer, data-science

I am working on the classic problem of converting time period in strings to equivalent numeric days. The below table should give you a brief idea.

```
| Input String | Expected Numeric Output in days | 
|--------------|---------------------------------|
| 7 weeks      |      49 
| 100 days     |      100
| four months  |      120 
| 3 months     |      90 
| mid march    |      75
```

What is the best way to go about to implement and achieve the same solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is a surprisingly tricky problem. You can get a long way with [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but like any regex-based solutions it will have low recall (won't be able to deal all possible ways of specifying a date):

```
import dateparser

# work fine
print(dateparser.parse("3 months"))  # 2020-08-02 17:02:07.194608
print(dateparser.parse("four months"))
print(dateparser.parse("march"))
print(dateparser.parse("7 weeks"))  # 2020-09-14 17:02:07.200475

# doesn't work
print(dateparser.parse("mid march"))  # None
```

and to convert the parsed interval:

```
print((datetime.now() - dateparser.parse("1 week")).seconds)
```

which returns 86399 (second between now and one week from now).

Note that some of your examples are different, e.g. 7 weeks is a duration, where as mind-march is a (poorly specified) point in time. What would you expect a working algorithm to return for "mid march"?